# Calculate sum for group records in MySQL

Tags: mysql, select, join, sum

I have this table of orders

```
| ORDER_ID | PRODUCT | CUSTOMER  | QTY | DATE
---------------------------------------------
|       1  |  shoes  |    Nick   |   1 | 01/01/2016
|       2  |  shirts |    Nick   |   5 | 02/02/2016
|       3  |  shoes  |    Paul   |  10 | 03/03/2016
|       4  |  shirts |    Paul   |  20 | 04/04/2016
```

So, How can I achieve this report result with ONE Select Statement?

```
| Date_of_Order |  Customer  |  Quantity | PRODUCT_TOTAL_SALES |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
|   01/01/2016  |   Nick     |     1     |      shoes : 11     |  
|   02/02/2016  |   Nick     |    10     |     shirts : 25     |
|   03/03/2016  |   Paul     |     5     |      shoes : 11     |
|   04/04/2016  |   Paul     |    20     |     shirts : 25     |
```

I know how to use `concat(column1, ' ', column2)` to create a combined column but I haven't succeed to add a sum for a grouped item there. When I try with left join I get the sum for a product ...BUT its always the whole sum and its not related to the dates of the order so when I try to filter the results on my query for a certain period I still get 11 for shoes and 25 for shirts...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I formatted your tables a bit - you can always highlight text and use the `{}` editor toolbar button or `ctl-k` to format it as a code block, which applies fixed-with, syntax highlighting where applicable, and avoids extra line breaks.

Comment: can you also add the query that generated the report and the report you want to obtain?

Answer (score 0):

You can `group by` multiple columns and get the sum for the smallest group.

If you want the daily sales, then instead of `GROUP BY product` use `GROUP BY product, date`

```
SELECT
    o.`date` AS Date_of_Order,
    SUM(o.qty) as Total_Quantity,
    CONCAT(o.product, ':', SUM(o.qty))
FROM
    orders o
GROUP BY product, `date`
ORDER BY `date`
```

Comment: I think I group by multiple columns. Can you share the code which will provide the expected result (and the sum will be relative to any filtered dates?)

Comment: this is incompatible with `sql_mode=only_full_group_by`

Comment: @mitkosoft what makes you think so?

Comment: MySQL say so :) `[Err] 1055 - Expression #2 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'test.o.customer' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by`

Comment: @mitkosoft - You're right. The customer name is not relevant in the current form of the report.
Sam - if you want the customer name to be relevant, you'll have to GROUP BY customer also

Comment: @TudorConstantin, it will have same inconsistency again as `o.qty` is not part of GROUP BY clause.

Comment: you're right. I corrected it to display the total quantity instead

Answer (score 0):

Simple additional `SELECT` from same table can do that for entire period:

```
SELECT
    o.`date` AS Date_of_Order,
    o.Customer,
    o.qty as Quantity,
    (SELECT
            CONCAT(oo.product, ':', SUM(oo.qty))
        FROM
            orders oo
        WHERE
            oo.product = o.product
    ) PRODUCT_TOTAL_SALES
FROM
    orders o
```

Output:

```
+---------------+----------+----------+---------------------+
| Date_of_Order | Customer | Quantity | PRODUCT_TOTAL_SALES |
+---------------+----------+----------+---------------------+
| 01/01/2016    | Nick     |        1 | shoes:11            |
| 02/02/2016    | Nick     |        5 | shirts:25           |
| 03/03/2016    | Paul     |       10 | shoes:11            |
| 04/04/2016    | Paul     |       20 | shirts:25           |
+---------------+----------+----------+---------------------+
4 rows in set
```

If you want to filter by certain period, you must include it in both:

```
SELECT
    o.`date` AS Date_of_Order,
    o.Customer,
    o.qty as Quantity,
    (SELECT
            CONCAT(oo.product, ':', sum(oo.qty))
        FROM
            orders oo
        WHERE
            oo.product = o.product
            AND STR_TO_DATE(oo.`date`,'%d/%m/%Y') BETWEEN '2016-01-01' AND '2016-03-03'
    ) PRODUCT_TOTAL_SALES
FROM
    orders o
WHERE 
    STR_TO_DATE(o.`date`,'%d/%m/%Y') BETWEEN '2016-01-01' AND '2016-03-03'
```

Output:

```
+---------------+----------+----------+---------------------+
| Date_of_Order | customer | Quantity | PRODUCT_TOTAL_SALES |
+---------------+----------+----------+---------------------+
| 01/01/2016    | Nick     |        1 | shoes:11            |
| 02/02/2016    | Nick     |        5 | shirts:5            |
| 03/03/2016    | Paul     |       10 | shoes:11            |
+---------------+----------+----------+---------------------+
3 rows in set
```

Comment: This is how I did it until now ...but the thing is that somehow I cannot filter it inside the inner select statement because the filter the user will use is on some other AJAX/Graph script which presents the table on the page and I am trying to achieve that with just one filter on the final column .. on the presented table. I think I need to have as column date the date of the inner "select" ...